# HAL_UART_Transmit_IT sending data twice

Tags: c, stm32, uart, stm32f4discovery, hal

I am trying to establish UART communication between a PC and a STM32f407-DISC1 board using an arduino nano as a middle man.
The PC sends 'r' to the arduino to indicate a request.
The request is then communicated to the stm32 with a GPIO interrupt, which then should be transmitting 480 bytes of data using HAL_UART_Transmit_IT.
It however sends the data twice, with only a single request made.

The code on the STM32 is generated by STM32CubeMX

Data request made by the arduino

```cpp
void loop() {
    digitalWrite(4, 0); // Clear EXTI11 line.

    if (mySerial.available() && received < 480) {   // STM32 sending data and is not done.
        buff[received] = mySerial.read();           // Append received data to the buffer.
        received++;
    }
    if (received >= 480) {                          // If the buffer is full
        received = 0;                               // transmit it to PC.
        Serial.println(buff);
    }


    if (Serial.available()) {
        if (Serial.read() == 'r') {     // PC requests data from the STM32
            digitalWrite(4, 1);         // Triggers STM32 EXTI11 line.
            while (Serial.available())  // Empty the buffer.
                Serial.read();
        }
    }
}
```

data transmission on the STM32

```c
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void)
{
    // Make sure that the interrupt is the good one.
    if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(data_req_IRQ_GPIO_Port, data_req_IRQ_Pin)) {
        if (is_sending_data == FALSE)   // If no transmission is happening
            should_send_data = TRUE;    // raise transmission flag.
    }

    // IRQ handling stuff...
}

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef * huart) {
    is_sending_data = FALSE;    // Transmition is completed, unblock requests.
}

void main(void){
    // Init and other stuff...

    while (1) {
        if (should_send_data == TRUE) { // If data was requested
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD5_GPIO_Port, LD5_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart3, matrice, 480);    // Start transmission by interrupt.
            is_sending_data = TRUE;                         // Block requests.
            should_send_data = FALSE;                       // Clear flag.
        }
    // matrice acquisition stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the GPIO interrupt edge or level triggered?

Comment: It is rising edge triggered and I make sure the pin is `high` before rising the flag in the interrupt

Comment: I think you missed (or did not show on your code) clearing the interruption bits. Shouldn't that be done manually?

Comment: Clearing the interruption bits? If you meant for the EXTI interrupt, I left out `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_11);` from the `EXTI15_10_IRQHandler` call, is that what you mean?

Comment: I agree with @MarcosG about IT flag management. You should check that he function `EXTI15_10_IRQHandler` is clearing the flag corresponding to the GPIO pin properly. I suggest you add a (static or global) counter in the IRQ handler to check if you execute it several times. If not, there is probably a race conditions between your flags `is_sending_data'` and `should_send_data`

Comment: could you explain what you mean by race condition @GuillaumePetitjean? I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Race condition was perhaps a bad expression. I just meant that your flags are modified in handler mode (UART callback called by UART IRQ handler and GPIO handler) and thread mode. But there is no synchro mechanism like mutex. It's just an hypothesis, I didn't analyse deeply.

Comment: oh I think I understand, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I found a solution, but it involved just rethinking my approach, so sorry for those looking for an answer to this problem.

I removed the arduino middle man by replacing it with a USB to RS232 converter and made UART reception work by interrupt. The STM detects the 'r' character which triggers the data communication. 
Here is the interrupt part:

```c
void USART3_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if (USART3->SR & UART_IT_RXNE) {    // If a byte is received
        rxBuff[0] = (uint8_t) (huart3.Instance->DR & (uint8_t) 0xFF);   // Read it.
        __HAL_UART_FLUSH_DRREGISTER(&huart3);   // Clear the buffer to avoid errors.
        rx_new_char_flag = TRUE;    // Raise the new_char flag.
        return; // Stops the IRQHandler from disabling interrupts.
    }
}
```

and the gestion of that in the main

```c
while (1) {
    if (rx_new_char_flag == TRUE) {
        rx_new_char_flag = FALSE;
        if (rxBuff[0] == 'r') {
            rxBuff[0] = 0;
            HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart3, matrice, 480); // Start transmission by interrupt.
            }
        }
```

On the PC side, to optimize performance, instead of waiting for the full 480 bytes, I wait for only one character, if one is received I keep reading the serial port, as shown in the code bellow

```cpp
int i = 0;
do {
    ReadFile(m_hSerial, &temp_rx[i], 1, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
    i++;
} while (dwBytesRead > 0 && i < 480);
for (int j = i; j < 480; j++)  // If the transmission is incomplete, fill the buffer with 0s to avoid garbage data.
    temp_rx[j] = 0;

if(i>=480)  // If all the bytes has been received, copy the data in the working buffer.
    std::copy(std::begin(temp_rx), std::end(temp_rx), std::begin(m_touch_state));
```

This works well with pretty decent performance, so that may be a permanent solution to my problem.